# How to split a NAME and ADDRESS, and print them separately

Tags: java

I'm starting with this String:

```
"NAME-RAHUL KUMAR CHOUDHARY ADDRESS-RAJDHANWAR DISTRICT-GIRIDIH STATE-JHARKHAND PIN CODE-825412"
```

I want to split the name and address, and print it like this:

```
NAME:RAHUL KUMAR CHOUDHARY , DDRESS-RAJDHANWAR DISTRICT-GIRIDIH STATE-JHARKHAND PIN CODE-825412. like this
```

This is what I have so far:

```
String str_colArow3 = colArow3.getContents();
//Display the cell contents

System.out.println("Contents of cell Col A Row 3: \""+str_colArow3 + "\"");

if(str_colArow3.contains("NAME"))
{

}
else if(str_colArow3.contains("ADDRESS"))
{

}
```

Comment: Use something about `Token`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string = "NAME-RAHUL KUMAR CHOUDHARY ADDRESS-RAJDHANWAR DISTRICT-GIRIDIH STATE-JHARKHAND PIN CODE-825412";
String[] parts = string.split("-");

string = "Name: " + parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length() - 7) 
       + "\nAdress: " + parts[2] + " - " + parts[3]
       + "\nPin Code: " + parts[5];
```

Something like this. Check out the split() method for strings, your string is a bit poorly formatted to use this, though. You have to adjust for your own needs.

**Edit:** Better way to do this, with different string input.

```
String string = "RAHUL KUMAR CHOUDHARY:RAJDHANWAR:GIRIDIH:JHARKHAND:825412";
String[] parts = string.split(":");

string = "Name: " + parts[0] + "\n" 
       + "Address: " + parts[1] + "\n"
       + "District: " + parts[2] + "\n"
       + "State: " + parts[3] + "\n"
       + "Pin Code: " + parts[4] + "\n";
```

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong array index. It should work now. But you should still try to figure out how to parse this yourself using the way I showed you, since this is now the output you want. Also try to get a better input string if you can. Something like "Name:Adress:District:State:Pincode" is easier to split, your string would then look like this: "RAHUL KUMAR:RAJDHANWAR:GIRIDIH:JHARKHAND:825412" A lot more compact and easier to parse.

Comment: can u please tell me how get regualr Expression for that given String

Comment: String[] parts = string.split(":"); The split() method uses the symbol given in the parentheses to find out where to split the string. It creates an array which you can access like this then: parts[0] where 0 is the part of the array you want to access.

Comment: actually i have different type of data so i want pic that String On the basis of regular expression and spiting and Printing like ur way

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you want, sorry. I've added more code to my original reply, check it out to see what would be a better way to handle the information.